# Graphical grub menu for 16.04

Tags: 16.04, grub2, gui

3 years ago, someone asked if you could have a [graphical grub menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/435487/graphical-grub-menu). Is there anything like this that is still supported and compatible with 16.04LTS?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/), a graphical boot manager.

[image]

I did a trial install of it once and it worked well.

The [maintainer](https://askubuntu.com/users/93977/rod-smith) of it is an active member of askubuntu.com

This [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760875/any-downside-to-using-refind-instead-of-grub) is not a duplicate, but the answer to it gives a good overview of the difference between GRUB and rEFInd.